# How do I override a database timeout when importing data?

Tags: python, database

When I click "download data files" from a site, it says the file will be available for **5 minutes**.

If I try to import the file into python using the url after 5 minutes is up I will get an error.

As I am downloading years of data from over 900 sites, I cannot click "download data files" every 5 minutes for each day of each site.

I would like to figure out a way to stop the links from timing out and any ideas are much appreciated!

P.S. This is the specific error I get:

**HTTP Status 404 - /database-browser/public/
type Status report
message /database-browser/public/
description The requested resource (/database-browser/public/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/5.5.27**

P.P.S If I never clicked "download data files" in the first place, I just edit the date in the url from 2015-02-01 to 2014-02-01 for example, is there any way to access the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like a database timeout per se; it looks like they have a script which creates a temporary file, gives you five minutes to download it, then deletes the file.

The obvious solution would be to call to

```
http://sid.stanford.edu/database-browser/retrieve?starttime=2015-02-01T00.00.00&endtime=2015-02-02T00.00.00&res=1000x200&TZ=GMT&mss=true&sss=true&goes=true&goesFlareStrength=C1.0
```

(with appropriate GET parameters substituted),

parse the resulting HTML to see what files it produced (may be 1 to many),
then grab the file/s before it/they disappear.

This could be easily automated with the `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` modules.

On the other hand, why not contact someone there and ask about getting better access to the data? It could be a lot more convenient to just ask for a couple of burned DVDs.

Comment: In the url you've given is there a way to retrieve only the data from one site at a time so that only one file is created? Thanks so much for your help!